Dotenvx injected variables not picked up in constructor
I am trying to use an environment variable in a constructor function in Javascript but with no success.
After doing some research I found that my issue was similar to this
How to make .env variables work inside JS class constructors?
but with some few differences.
The solution here mentions to use preload in the dotenv library to preload your variables so they are picked up in the constructor.
However, when you read the dotenv docs, it is recommended to use the library dotenvx instead

Note: Consider using dotenvx instead of preloading. I am now doing (and recommending) so.

My issue comes up when using dotenvx, I have added it to my scripts and can see that it says the env variables are injected.

I can confirm this because the value of the variable is logged in my entry file app.js
app.post('/start', startRunLimiter, (req, res) => {

    console.log(process.env.MAIN_APP_URL); //-> this works

But not picked up in my constructor function in a different file Dashboard.js
 constructor() {
        super();
        console.log(`test` + process.env.MAIN_APP_URL); // -> prints undefined
        this.setUrl(process.env.MAIN_APP_URL);
    }

How do i get the variables to be picked up in my constructor function?

Where and when are you calling that constructor?

@Bergi in the entry file app.js after a POST request has been made to the endpoint above

The endpoint starts the cypress headless runner which runs my E2E tests. The constructor is being called in one of the tests

@damian-sketch sometimes (in rare cases), this is related to subshell commands. https://dotenvx.com/docs/advanced/run-shell-expansion. but that said, do you have more code you can share? if you're seeing it in your backend, you should see it in Dashboard.js. or is Dashboard.js a front-end only bit of code?
